# Trying to delete a file with the AWS gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

In rails console, I do:

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new(APP_CONFIG['amazon_access_key_id'], APP_CONFIG['amazon_secret_access_key'])
s3.delete('bucketname', 'uploads/users/14/photo/33/foo.jpg')
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<Aws::S3:0x0000010650b228>
```

I read this [doc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/aws/2.5.6/frames). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new(APP_CONFIG['amazon_access_key_id'], APP_CONFIG['amazon_secret_access_key'])
s3.bucket('bucketname').delete_key('uploads/users/14/photo/33/foo.jpg')
```

Comment: Hi Spike. Shouldn't delete do the same thing though? Based on the description in the doc. It seems so. Maybe I am misunderstanding something here

Comment: When I read the doc I didn't see a delete method for Aws::S3, only for Aws::S3::Bucket. So I'm getting a bucket object and then calling delete_key on that. Does my example work for you?