# Add existing image URL (s3) to my model to destroy image on model destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a service that creates images and uploads them to s3. This service is separate from my Rails app, but the Rails app is responsible to control those s3 files.

I have a model Page, and at some point I get from this extenral service, the S3 url.

Right now I do this:

```
@page  = Page.find(3)
@page.s3_url = url
```

And this is cool. However, I am looking to do the following:

When that @page gets destroyed, I need to remove the s3 file. And also, I would like to be able to create a thumbnail when I do @page.s3_url.

I have tried with Paperclip but it doesn't deal well when the image is already in S3. Which approach should I take in order to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to delete a file with the AWS gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390827/trying-to-delete-a-file-with-the-aws-gem)

Comment: Use the official AWS/S3 Ruby gem like the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390827/trying-to-delete-a-file-with-the-aws-gem does and delete the file that way